# import openpgp in angular2

Tags: angular, openpgp.js

I am porting an openpgp.js application from Node.js to Angular2. It works fine in Node.js, but in Angular2 I get an error:
TS2305: Module '"/Users/barry/Angular2/keyManager/node_modules/@types/openpgp/ts3.2"' has no exported member 'openpgp'.

In Node.js I am using `var openpgp = require('openpgp');`
I need an equivalent for Angular2.

I've also tried `import {openpgp} from '/Users/barry/Angular2/keyManager/node_modules/openpgp/dist/openpgp.js';` and 
 `import {openpgp} from '/Users/barry/Angular2/keyManager/node_modules/openpgp/src/openpgp.js';`
I could not find an 'openpgp.d.ts' file.
My package.json has
    "@types/openpgp": "^4.0.4", and
     "openpgp": "^4.4.7"

```
//  GenKeys.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {openpgp} from 'openpgp';
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it after looking at issues in the openpgpjs/openpgpjs git. Use `import * as openpgp from 'openpgp';`